# Alias for a notion/term

Tags: alias, translations

I write my thesis in my native language and at the moment I don't know how to translate a specific term the best. I use the term pretty often and would like to make an alias at the moment and do the translation later on. There shouldn't be any problems concerning conjugation since it's a noun.
Do you know any solution to this?

Comment: You can use a macro `\newcommand{\myterm}{word}`.

Comment: “shouldn't be any problems concerning conjugation” – what about declination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{matrix}{name={matrix},plural={matrices},description={}}

\begin{document}

\Gls{matrix} at the start of a sentence, or \gls{matrix}
mid-sentence or lots of \glspl{matrix}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Matrix at the start of a sentence, or matrix mid-sentence or lots of matrices.]

Later on you can just modify the definition.

Edit: Here's a slightly more compact version:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[index]{glossaries}

\newterm
 [name={matrix},plural={matrices}]% text
 {matrix}% label

\begin{document}

\Gls{matrix} at the start of a sentence, or \gls{matrix}
mid-sentence or lots of \glspl{matrix}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define yourself a macro that you can conveniently change later on (here `\myterm`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}
\newcommand{\myterm}{foo}
\begin{document}
Some text describing \myterm.
\end{document}
```

It is usually a wise decision to start that from the beginning for mathematical symbols as you can -- then -- later on change the nomenclature at your will without going through the whole document. Or the will of your supervisor/ editor/ journal ;).